# Habilitar botón al llenar el formulario dentro

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Qué puedo hacer para habilitar un botón cuando el formulario dentro de un `GroupBox` este lleno y que lo inhabilite cuando uno se encuentre vacío?
Entiendo que pudiera utilizar un `forech` para leer todos los `TextBox` pero no entiendo la manera o como seleccionar lo que hay dentro del `GroupBox`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Jeff puedo responder a tu pregunta, pero deberias ser un poco mas precisio, como por ejemplo poner le codigo donde quieres hacer eso o mostrar una imagen de como quieres que funciones, asi casi no se te puede ayudar :V

Comment: listo ya añadí la foto

Answer (score 2):

Creando un array con cada uno de los TextBox y preguntando si algunos de ellos no tiene texto escrito, entonces se deshabilita el button. Esto curre cuando uno de los TextBox pierde el focus:

```
        TextBox[] textboxs;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.LostFocus += ValidarTextBox;
            textBox2.LostFocus += ValidarTextBox;
            textBox3.LostFocus += ValidarTextBox;
            textboxs = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3 };
        }

        private void ValidarTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.button1.Enabled = !textboxs.Any(X => String.IsNullOrEmpty(X.Text));
        }
```

Aun asi te recomiendo que simplemente valides si el usuario escribio  en todos los `TextBox` al momento de dar clic al ya que sobrecarga menos la app:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool datosCorrectos = !textboxs.Any(X => String.IsNullOrEmpty(X.Text));

    if (datosCorrectos)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Registro correcto!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Complete todos campos");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre el evento leave para cada uno de tus txt

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text != String.Empty && textBox2.Text != String.Empty && textBox2.Text != String.Empty)
  {
      //Significa que hay texto en tus 3 txt
      tuboton.Enabled == true ; //activas tu boton
  }      
}
```

Comment: Si usas esta forma, creo que deberías completar con `else tuboton.Enabled=false;` por aquello de que podrían llenar los tres campos, y una vez que se habilita el botón, borrar alguno de los textbox.